# Is there a mode or some way to use grep inside emacs then jump to the referenced?

Tags: emacs, grep

I'm looking for a useful way to use `grep` from inside `emacs`.  I generally run a `grep` command to find references in the source tree and then use `emacs` to open the file and then jump to the line indicated with the `-n` flag to `grep`.  However, I'm guessing with `emacs` I could do better.  It would be nice if the resulting view maintained the colorization provided by normal `grep` in the terminal.  Granted this wouldn't be universal, but at least the intent.

Is there a mode or some way to use `grep` inside `emacs` then jump to the referenced?

Comment: What have you tried?  E.g. the first entry in the "Tools" menu says "Search files (Grep)" which sounds like it might arguably be vaguely related.

Comment: `C-h r i grep`.  It's not hard to ask Emacs - one of the things that makes Emacs useful. `i` in the manuals is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, <kbd>M-x grep</kbd> and <kbd>M-x rgrep</kbd> (`r` for recursive) are already there - and can be accessed from menu `Tools` --> `Search files (Grep)`.

See [27.4 Searching with Grep under Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html).

You might also find [<kbd>M-x dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html) and [<kbd>M-x project-query-regexp</kbd>](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/project.el) useful.